# My PHP Session Not Properly Redirected

Tags: php, login-script

Any one can help me my session isn't properly redireted when I set a Session 
Here My code:

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
   if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
     header('Location: profile.php');
}
   else{
     header('Location: loigin.php');
}
```

Thankyou I hope any one can help me :)

Comment: What does it do, what doesn't it do? More details are required... Might want to take the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) again...

Comment: i can't understand what you want through this code?

Comment: You should add more details, maybe  `loigin.php` should be `login.php`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this code? Where did you learn English? And what have you tried to achieve the wanted goal?

Comment: You've got your logic turned around: When the `user_id` is set in the session, you direct to `loigin.php` (login?). Based on the names of the files, it should be the other way around. Just remove the `!` before `isset()`.

Comment: Dear All , yes Sure login.php sorry for that  :)

My goal is if user not login they can't access "profile.php" page and redirected to login.php ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be like this based on logic..

```
ob_start();
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
   if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) // if the session is not set it will redirect to login.php
{
     header('Location: loigin.php');
}
   else{ // else redirect to profile.php
     header('Location: profile.php');
}
```

Comment: otherwise you can follow @jeroen idea.

Comment: My goal is if user not login they can't access "profile.php" page and redirected to login.php

and if they have login in "login.php" the will redirected to "profile.php"

Comment: I've use your code but still not properly redirected :(

Comment: Actually where it is redirecting??

Comment: to Profile.php after checking the session is started

Comment: change `$_SESSION['user_id']` to `$_SESSION['usr_id']` in profile.php.. because you declared the session as `$_SESSION['usr_id']`

Comment: Ouhh its work !!. you are my angels :)
thank you very much!!